# Objective-C: Cannot access synthesized variable

Tags: objective-c, properties, cocos2d-iphone, synthesize

I'm using Cocos2d and looking to access a variable (CakesEaten) from another CCScene.

```
// in MainScene.h
@interface MainScene : CCScene{
    int CakesEaten;
}
@property int CakesEaten;

// in MainScene.m
@implementation
@synthesize CakesEaten;

// at the top of ScoreScreen.m
#import "MainScene.h"
// in the ScoreScreen.m init method
MainScene.CakesEaten = 9999
```

Gives an error of: Property "CakesEaten" not found on object of type MainScene. It's the only error that I receive when building.

Comment: The code provided makes no reference to `TomatoesKilled` whatsoever.

Comment: Where is this line that references a property called `TomatoesKilled`? That's not mentioned anywhere in the code snippet that you posted. Also, generally properties and variable names don't start with capital letters. Generally you use camelCaseVariableNames where the first letter is lowercase and the start of each subsequent word within the name is capitalized.

Comment: Opps that's embarrassing. I'm a beginner, so thanks for the naming suggestion. I edited it so that it's CakesEaten (it was originally CakesEaten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access *any* property, synthesized or not, you need an instance of the class:

```
MainScene *scene = [[MainScene alloc] init];
scene.CakesEaten = 9999;
```

Note: the latest editions of Xcode do not require `@synthesize`, unless you would like to change the name for the variable that is used by default. You can safely remove that line, along with the declaration of the member variable.

The end result should look like this:

```
@interface MainScene : CCScene
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int CakesEaten;
@end
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 0):

Not MainScene, just self.

```
self.CakesEaten = 9999
```